# Force a process to Ophan in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm trying to troubleshoot a high memory usage / high cpu issue on my ASP.NET site. The problem is only happening on live so I'd like to take a crash dump of the work process.

The issue I'm having is due to the high memory usage the crash dump takes 4-5 mins and during this time the site is unavailable. I can setup process orphaning on the worker process and grab a dump but how do I force the process to orphan? I'd like to get a crash dump without disrupting site traffic.

I'm running IIS 8 on Windows Server 2013 R2

Comment: Have you tried debugging remotely?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with a single request, its a problem when there is high load. I've used windbg to troubleshoot these problems before I just need a way to get the dump and not kill the site.